# How to implement with OO a set of keys in C++ for a kdtree

Tags: c++, tree, kdtree

I need to implement a B+ tree which is adapted to be a *k*-d tree. As a short
explanation of this, a *k*-d tree is like a binary tree except that at its
nodes it has a multi-valued key, that is a key with several values. And it will
also be a B+ tree cause the internal nodes are only meant to store 1 of the
values of the key and the real data is stored at the leaf nodes. Here's a short
graphical explanation of it:

[image: short graphical explanation]

My leaf nodes have space for 2 elements, when I add the first 2 everything
works fine, till I add the third and I must make a split. For that, since I
choose the first value of the key to be the one that defines the order, I take
the median value of all three elements and the result is 27, so all elements
less than 27 go to the left and those bigger or equal than go to the right.

When I add the 4th element, since Tom and Linda have age less than 27 they
already completed a leaf node, son adding Dom makes the node to split again,
but this time I must switch which value of the key defines the order which is
Social Security Number. Again I take the median value and the result is 530, so
all those with SS Number less than 530 go to the left, and so on.

Resulting with the final *k*-d tree, with certain values of the key as index in
the internal nodes, and the complete key at the leaf nodes.

Now my question is, after explaining the context, how can I implement a
solution for the keys, given that I do have to store at the leaf nodes the
complete key, but at the internal nodes I only use one of the values of the
key.

You can notice the resemblance with a database, where we have multiple fields
with values, and we can sort the information with different fields at the same
time, one more important than the next and so on.

I thought of making a `class` named `Key` or any other name, with atributes that
hold all the values, for the above example, it could be `int` for age and `int` for
SSNumber and `string` for name. But my problem is, what if my client decides he
wants to add more values, then my class would grow bigger and bigger. Is this a
good OO decision? Can I implement this another way and still be OO? I know my
imagination can be poor, but since I can assume the client wants more values I
could make some sort of list that holds my values, then it means I would have
to make a list that can support any type of data, which doesn't sound like an OO
approach. Any ideas?

Also I want to add that, since at some point of my algorithm of the tree ill
need to take 1 attribute of the key to use as the index in the tree, I must
support this as well.

I would really appreciate an idea of how to solve this by following an OO
approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `Key` an array of `KeyPart`, then each type of key value (age, ss#) can subclass from `KeyPart`.  Then each internal node of your tree can store a single `KeyPart` and a key part index (to know what part it is the split of).  The leaves can store the full `Key`.

Comment: This is WOW, awesome solution, thank you very much!!! Just 1 question, im not sure what you mean by "key part index" like a number that maps each subclass? Anyway i'm very confident now that i can work with this idea i can figure it out the rest. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Disregard my question about the key part index, i totally get it now. Your answer is just what i needed.